# SignalR and Hub Persistance

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I am trying out SignalR, and i don't quite understand how to call methods from my client in a way that it calls the same hub.

i have two methods in my hub:

```
    private ctlDataManager myManager;
    public void StartConnection()
    {
        myManager = new ctlDataManager("test");

        myManager.UpdateItemEvent += myManager_UpdateItemEvent;

        myManager.Connect();
    }

    public void StopConnection()
    {
        myManager.Disconnect();
    }
```

And in my client i try to call them like this:

```
var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;

    $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function (state) {
            $("#submit").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                notificationHub.server.startConnection();
                return false;
            });

            $("#stop").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                notificationHub.server.stopConnection();
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Now when i click on the start button it works fine it starts it and receives data too.
But when i click the stop button it throws an instance of an object error.
It appears that 'myManager' is null. It's almost as a new hub were open. Naturally i need it to be the same one as i need to close the connection.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, the server-side hub class is not persisted.  Therefore, the myManager object is created with each method call from a client.  My advice would be to declare myManager elsewhere in your application that you can assure 100% up-time, and have your server-side hub methods communicate with it that way.

One way for you to verify this is to debug the constructor of your hub class.  You will notice that it is called for every client->server-side method call.

Comment: Thanks SeanP. you are right. it does get created everytime. I have now created a static ConcurrentDictionary to keep my connection objects in and let different clients keep track of the connections with an id i pass back and forth, between the hub and client. Not sure if this is a great idea, but will see soon enough.

Comment: No problem, I ran into the same scenario myself.  I am not sure of the best approach to this, but it all depends on what sort of application you're working with.  For my MVC4 web application, I placed the dictionary/list object within Global.asax.  I then back up the current state and all necessary ID's to a database periodically.